# Accessing a case class annotation

Tags: scala, scala-reflect

```
case class FieldName(field: String) extends scala.annotation.StaticAnnotation
@FieldName("foo") trait Foo
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

symbolOf[Foo].annotations.head
// ann: Annotation = FieldName("type")
```

How do I access the annotation as a `FieldName` object? The doc mentions [tree.children.tail](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.1/scala-reflect/scala/reflect/api/Annotations$Annotation.html#scalaArgs:List[Annotations.this.Tree]), but there's no types to be had.

Comment: Yeah. Oops. Fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really want the instance of `FieldName` the best I can think of is using a `ToolBox`:

```
scala> case class FieldName(field: String) extends scala.annotation.StaticAnnotation
defined class FieldName

scala> @FieldName("foo") trait Foo
defined trait Foo

scala> import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

scala> val annotation = symbolOf[Foo].annotations.head
annotation: reflect.runtime.universe.Annotation = FieldName("foo")

scala> import scala.tools.reflect.ToolBox
import scala.tools.reflect.ToolBox

scala> val tb = runtimeMirror(getClass.getClassLoader).mkToolBox()
tb: scala.tools.reflect.ToolBox[reflect.runtime.universe.type] = scala.tools.reflect.ToolBoxFactory$ToolBoxImpl@1b26a499

scala> tb.eval(tb.untypecheck(annotation.tree)).asInstanceOf[FieldName]
res10: FieldName = FieldName(foo)
```

With `.tree.children.tail` you can access the arguments passed to `FieldName` without creating the actual instance.

```
scala> annotation.tree.children.tail.map{ case Literal(Constant(field)) => field } 
res11: List[Any] = List(foo)
```

---

If you just want all `FieldName` annotations and extract their value, you can do this:

```
scala> val fields = symbolOf[Foo].annotations.withFilter( 
     |   a => a.tree.tpe <:< typeOf[FieldName] 
     | ).flatMap( 
     |   a => a.tree.children.tail.map{ case Literal(Constant(field)) => field } 
     | )
fields: List[Any] = List(foo)
```

Comment: May be a bit of XY - accessing by type would make sure I don't catch any other annotations by mistake. But it would actually be sufficient to check it's the correct annotation and extracting the value.

Comment: @Reactormonk Oh ok, I see what you mean now.

Comment: If I have more than one annotation, how can I know which fields belong to which annotation?

Comment: The ToolBox method works, but is terribly slow, which renders it unusable for my purposes. Is there a way to make it faster?

Comment: @raimohanska I think you'll just have to extract `field` manually, and if you really need a `FieldName` instance just reconstruct it from the extracted `field`.

Comment: @bashan With `a.tree.tpe <:< typeOf[FieldName]` you can check whether the annotation you're processing is a `FieldName` or not.